# primefaces p:selectManyMenu listener not listening

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to fire an event when the user picks something from a `selectManyMenu`.

```
<p:selectManyMenu value="#{radicadoOficioBean.localidadesSeleccionadas}">
    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{radicadoOficioBean.listenerdt}" process="@this"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{radicadoOficioBean.localidadSIs}"/>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

And

```
public void listenerdt(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
    System.out.println("oh!");
}
```

Are not working. However, if i use `selectOneMenu` instead of `selectManyMenu`, listener listens. I tried with the default event, with "change" too and nothing works.

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Comment: Look like a bug in PrimeFaces side. I'd report it to them.

Comment: Which version of PrimeFaces were you having the problem with, and which did you upgrade to that solved the issue?

Comment: hulo, problem:3.4. solution: 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dowloaded latest primefaces' jar,  restarted server and now things work fine.